# MySQL select all rows but exclude same value

Tags: mysql, sql

All I have table in MySQL as bellow.

```
+---------+-------------+---------------+
| item_no | item_name   | item_location |
+---------+-------------+---------------+
| ITM145  |  laptop     | USA           |
| ITM146  |  camera     | USA           |
| ITM147  |  cd         | USA           |
| ITM148  |  phone      | USA           |
| ITM149  |  cd         | France        |
| ITM150  |  phone      | France        |
+---------+-------------+---------------+
```

The last tow items location is France, and the same items I have in USA, I want the query to return me as bellow exclude same value for location France.

```
+---------+-------------+---------------+
| item_no | item_name   | item_location |
+---------+-------------+---------------+
| ITM145  |  laptop     | USA           |
| ITM146  |  camera     | USA           |
+---------+-------------+---------------+
```

First try

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE item_location !='France'
GROUP BY item_name
```

FAIL
second try

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE item_location NOT IN('France')
GROUP BY item_name
```

Comment: So you don't want your query to return the `cd` / `phone` results from `USA`?

Comment: @ObsidianAge yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead using the `<>` operator (This is to omit 'France')

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE item_location <> 'France'
GROUP BY item_name
```

But if you want to get your results

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE item_location <> 'France' AND item_name IN ('laptop','camera')
GROUP BY item_name
```

To get the results that exclude item_name in France, you can try this

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE item_location <> 'France' AND item_name NOT IN (Select item_name FROM 
table where item_location = 'France')
GROUP BY item_name
```

Comment: thanks the third solution worked just fine, from 4 rows <code>3 total, Query took 0.0060 seconds.</code>

Comment: great, would appreciate if you could mark this as the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table
GROUP BY item_name
Having count(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

you want to get " laptop " and camera only there use this `SELECT * FROM country WHERE item_location ="usa" AND (item_name = "laptop" OR item_name = "camera") GROUP BY item_no`
if you want to selec

Comment: sorry I forget to mention I can't search by item name because there is thousand of items

Comment: then use SELECT * FROM country WHERE item_location ="usa"  LIMIT 2

Comment: Thanks but I can't use `LIMIT` as I said there is thousand of items,,, I don't required only tow items I required all items which not available in France.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN` with self table like this:

```
SELECT t.* FROM Table1 t
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT item_name FROM Table1 WHERE item_location = 'France'
) t2
ON t.item_name = t2.item_name
WHERE t2.item_name IS NULL
```

Output:

```
| item_no | item_name | item_location |
|---------|-----------|---------------|
|  ITM145 |    laptop |           USA |
|  ITM146 |    camera |           USA |
```

See this [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5402728/1).

To understand joins see [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/).

Comment: thanks the solution worked just fine, from 4 rows `3 total, Query took 0.0060 seconds.`  same as ryan-tan solution it make me confused I think subquery is better than join.